# Microsoft teams bot authentication blank screen

Tags: authentication, microsoft-teams, botframework

Trying to set up the auth flow for the bot authentication based on [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot).

I'm confused about multiple things: it seems like the auth flow for Microsoft teams bot is different from the bot framework auth flow. One has callbacks and sign-in cards and the other has some sort of dialog process?

1. I get that the teams will open a pop up to my auth site, and then my auth site will at one point call notifySuccess. But how does the Microsoft teams npm package know where to auth/notifySuccess to? It doesn't seem like the package requires any sort of chat id or bot id. [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/blob/master/src/views/oauth-callback-success.hbs)
2. I'm able to send back a sign-in card

```
    let signinCard = CardFactory.heroCard(
          'Click below to sign in',
          null,
          [
              {
                  type: ActionTypes.Signin,
                  value: 'https://localhost:4200/bot/auth/login',
                  title: 'Sign in'
              }
          ])
    await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [signinCard] });
```

Manifest valid domains

```
  "validDomains": [
    "localhost",
    "*.ngrok.io",
    "token.botframework.com"
  ]
```

But the sign-in link on the web version just opens up a new tab meanwhile sideloading from the desktop app opens up a blank popup
[image]

Highly appreciate it if someone knows what I'm missing

Comment: upload your manifest "validDomains"

Comment: @StefanWang Updated post with the validDomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your sign-in page is opened in an iframe inside Teams. And microsoftTeams.js communicates with Teams. This will let Teams know your website sent success notification.
2. Blank screen reason - incorrect `validDomains` in manifest file. `localhost:4200` should be included in `validDomains`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! 
the localhost was already in the domains and even with the port it wasn't working. However you did give me the inspiration to try it again but tunneled through ngrok and that worked! :)

Comment: @Leon ngrok will always work as it is SSL certified. You should visit localhost certificate to keychain if you're going to use localhost directly.

Comment: Gotcha I will look into localhost cert, and is it correct to say that after notifySuccess is verified, the token will be stored and be used for all the calls that go through the same endpoints.

Comment: You should handle the token in localStorage of microsoftTeams settings and check if it is valid. - work the same as tokens on the normal website.